# Bootstrap modals overlap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that simplified, looks like this :

```
<html>
<form>
//form contents here
//modal 1 here
<div class="modal fade" id="addTime" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addTimeLabel">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="modal-footer">
</div></div></div>
</form>
// insert duplicate modals here (2 of them)
</html>
```

The modal within the form works perfect, but when I click on buttons to call up modals 2 and 3, they appear within the 1st modals window?  How can I fix this?

Edit : If I delete the 1st modal entirely, 2 and 3 work perfect.... but I need the 1st modal too!

Comment: When u click modal 2 then u need to close modal 1 by java script

Comment: @varunsharma Here is my ooo : lets call the modals "a", "b", "c".  a is within the form, and works upon the button click calling its data target.  I can also close it fine.  b, c do not work at all on the normal dom, they populate within a's dom on click(i know this because i can click b, then a, and it shows b overlayed over a).  If I remove a totally, I can click b or c respectively(and close them properly).  I am not worried about closing modals via jquery(there is a close button for when user is done with modal).  I just want all the modals to work in my layout.

Comment: Check my answer. It is use full or not ?

Comment: @varunsharma I want to figure out why my modals b&c do not show whatsoever, I do not desire opening multiple modals at the same time

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#openBtn').click(function () {
        $('#myModal').modal({
            show: true
        })
    });

        $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function (event) {
            var zIndex = 1040 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
            $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
            }, 0);
        });


});
```

```css
/* crazy batman newspaper spinny thing */
 .rotate {
    transform:rotate(180deg);
    transition:all 0.5s;
}
.rotate.in {
    transform:rotate(1800deg);
    transition:all 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h2>Stacked Bootstrap Modal Example.</h2>
 <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">Content for the dialog / modal goes here.
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <p>more content</p>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br> <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal2" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"> <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade rotate" id="myModal2">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 2</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">Content for the dialog / modal goes here.
                <br>
                <br>
                <p>come content</p>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br> <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal3" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"> <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal3">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 3</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">Content for the dialog / modal goes here.
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br> <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal4" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"> <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal4">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 4</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">Content for the dialog / modal goes here.</div>
            <div class="modal-footer"> <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check this jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/CxdUQ/

Comment: Lol, I dont need "modalception", I just want 3 different modals, accessible from 3 different buttons on the main site, to work when clicked.  Please see my note added to above question